# Interpolation of points to raster data

Tags: java, gis, interpolation, raster

I am looking for a Java library that can convert data points with coordinates to raster data. Or a function where you can input the data points with their coordinates and get interpolated data from a given coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

For interpolation, these libraries might be useful.
[JSpline+](http://www.brothersoft.com/jspline+-1718.html)
[Java Numerical Library](http://www.roguewave.com/products/imsl-numerical-libraries/java-library.aspx)

Alternatively, you could use linear interpolation:

```
double lerp(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3)
{
    double y3 = y1 + (y2 - y1) * ((x3 - x1) / (x2 - x1));
    return y3;
}
```

Where (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) are to points you want to interpolate between, and (x3, y3) is the point you want to figure out.